# #1054 - Unknown column '***' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to set up my databases within PHPMyadmin, and I keep getting this error with this specific table after I set up the foreign keys. My other two tables setup fine. I am pulling my hair out with this as I cant figure out at all what the problem is.

The error I get when I try to insert a table within phpmyadmin is:

SQL query:

```
SELECT  `customerID` ,  `instrumentID` 
FROM  `project`.`customer` 
ORDER BY  `customer`.`instrumentID`
```

MySQL said:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'instrumentID' in 'field list'
```

`InstrumentID` is the primary key.

Has anyone any idea what the problem is? Thanks very much in advance. If you any specific info then please ask and Ill deliver it as im not sure what other info will be needed.

Comment: describe project.customer; ...post the output

Comment: `InstrumentID` is the primary key of the `customer` table? I would expect `customerID` to be the primary key.

Comment: I suspect there should be an `INNER JOIN` onto an `instrument` table there somewhere - that `InstrumentID` is the primary key on that table and that it doesn't exist in the customer table ... at a guess.

Comment: I now get "#1146 - Table 'project.project' doesn't exist" error. I get the original error when I click the "insert" button on phpmyadmin here: http://i.imgur.com/W5ljlPz.png

Comment: @Mihai yes project is the db.

Comment: The table you are trying to select from is "instruments", not "customer". So, `FROM project.customer`

Comment: @RobertRozas; Here is an image of the table describe in cmd: http://i.imgur.com/IYQrs1l.png or here is the text: Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra
customerID
varchar(6)
NO
PRI
NULL
email
varchar(30)
NO
NULL
firstName
varchar(30)
NO
NULL
lastName
varchar(30)
NO
NULL
phoneNumber
int(10)
YES
NULL
county
varchar(30)
NO
NULL

Comment: @CD001; It seems that by adding instrumentID to my customer table and indexing it will allow me to enter tables into the DB now without the error!

Comment: There is no instrumentID field in your table, just like the picture shows

Comment: I have a very bad feeling about this database.

Comment: @RobertRozas; Yes that seems to have fixed it, thanks guys. Forgive me, I am brand new to this stuff!

Comment: @Aioros; why whats the issue with you? This isnt a db that will be given to a client; I am only learning the basics currently and this is a test db.

Comment: Because there is no reason to have an `instrumentID` column in your `customer` table, especially when you already have the customer-instrument association in the `instruments` table. In `customer` you should only have information about the customer (id, name, email, whatever). In `instruments` you should have information about the instrument, so type, brand, price, and even the customer who bought it: which is a `customerID` column referencing the `customer` table.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by your table structure. The `customer` table doesn't have a `instrumentID` column, while the `instruments` table does.
So, your query should probably be:

```
SELECT  `customerID` ,  `instrumentID` 
FROM  `project`.`instruments` 
ORDER BY  `instruments`.`instrumentID`
```

Answer (score 0):

your mysql query syntax is not proper
i think table name don't have . so please verify your mysql query

```
SELECT  `customerID` ,  `instrumentID` FROM  `project`.`customer` ORDER BY  `customer`.`instrumentID`
```

problem is here "FROM  `project`.`customer`" you can create alias of table name like following

```
select `p.customerID`,`c.instrumentID` from customer as c,project as p ORDER BY c.instrumentID
```